# In an infinite maze of squares with p% walls, will you be boxed in?

Tags: mathematics, probability, mazes

If you are in an infinite maze of squares, where each border between two squares has a $p$% chance of being a wall, what is the probability $F(p)$ that you are trapped in a finite space?

For a better math definition of the problem:

First imagine a finite $n \times n$ grid of squares, where $n$ is odd. The border between two squares or between a square and the outside has a $p$% chance of being a wall. You start in the middle. $f(n,p)$ is the probability that you are trapped in the $n \times n$ maze. $F(p)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n,p)$. What is $F(p)$, or at least what can we know about it?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question? Or did you come up with it yourself?

Comment: Exactly this question is the subject of the field of _percolation_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_theory. It turns out that F(p) is 0 for p<1/2 and 1 for p>=1/2.

Comment: You mean F(p)<1 for p<1/2 - there is always a positive probability of the starting square being boxed in.

Comment: Er, sorry, yes. I was mixing up the probability that a given place (say the origin) is part of an infinite component, with the probability that there _is_ an infinite component. I don't know whether the precise question asked here is one whose answer is fully known.

Comment: @bobble I came up with the question myself when I was thinking about the backrooms but maybe someone else has thought of it before me.  I am not sure.